# Yoast search result error

Tags: wordpress, seo, multiple-languages, yoast, polylang

My site name is cloud nippon and the URL is https://www.cloudnippon.com.  It is a multilingual site. I used polylang plugin for multiple languages and I am using Yoast plugin for SEO purposes. In the Google search result page, the first language (English) shows correctly. When I search the other language (Japanese) it shows an error. How do I solve the error, please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Yoast Known Bug

You could try replacing

```
list( $language, $territory ) = explode( ‘_’, $locale );
```

with:

```
$language = WPSEO_Utils::get_language( $locale );
```

There is a similar Yoast bug filed [here](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/8473).

Have a look through the [Yoast GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues) to see if you can find your issue. If it's not already listed, add it to the one above or create a new one.

*The spelling of Yoast is **wrong** in your title. Would be good to correct it so people can understand your question better.

Let me know how you get on.